# PowerShell: Cannot write CustomDocumentProperties / GetType returns null

Tags: powershell, interop

I'm trying to write custom document properties of a .docx word document via powershell script.

Apparently it can't be done by simply accessing the properties like described in the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.customdocumentproperties?view=word-pia), but one has to invoke them by reflection like described by scripting guy [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-add-custom-properties-to-a-microsoft-word-document/) and [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-retrieve-the-custom-properties-of-a-microsoft-word-document/). (Does anyone know why that is?)

Following the code samples I was able to print the document properties to the shell output.

When executing the code that should write them, I get a NullReferenceException when trying to get the type of the CustomDocumentProperties property.

Here is a minimal example:

```
$file = "c:\Temp\Test.docx"

$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

$word.Visible = $false

$doc = $word.Documents.Open($file)

$customProperties = $doc.CustomDocumentProperties
Write-Host $customProperties # returns System.__ComObject [...] System.__ComObject, so it can't be null
$customProperties.GetType() # this line throws 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

$doc.Close()
$word.Quit()
```

How is it even possible that `GetType()` returns null?

I feel I'm stuck and like I'm missing something... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Calling `GetType()` on `CustomDocumentProperties` won't work because i'ts type isn’t known at compile time. Try using `InvokeMember`
See: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-add-custom-properties-to-a-microsoft-word-document/

Comment: @MartinIszac: In PowerShell, `.GetType()` is a _runtime_ operation (as most operations are). E.g., `$doc.GetType()` works just fine, and the fact that `$word.Documents.Open($file)` works implies that there's generally no need for `.InvokeMember()` - members can be accessed by name, directly.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This post **isn't a solution**, but provides some **background information**.

`$doc.CustomDocumentProperties` isn't `$null` (i.e. the absence of an object reference) in a *.NET* sense: it still references an object, albeit a [runtime-callable wrapper (RCW)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/runtime-callable-wrapper) for a *COM object* that  represents a null value *there*, i.e. the absence of a *COM* object / class instance.

You can verify this by using the [intrinsic `pstypenames` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#type-information) to report the (inheritance chain of) type name(s) of a given instance:

```bash
$doc.CustomDocumentProperties.pstypenames
```

Output:

```bash
System.__ComObject#{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
System.__ComObject
System.MarshalByRefObject
System.Object
```

`System.__ComObject` tells you that you're dealing with a *COM* object reference, and the `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}` tells you that this object reference points to *no object*, hence the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error message when attempting to call methods on this non-object.

---

Contrast this with trying to call a method on a true .NET `$null` value:

```bash
$null.Foo()
```

Output:

```bash
InvalidOperation: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

---

Now as for *why* [`$doc.CustomDocumentProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.customdocumentproperties) doesn't point to an actual object and how to remedy that, I don't know - if anybody knows, do tell us.